# jQuery Mobile anchor links to other page are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, anchor

I'm creating a jQuery Mobile web application.

This link, works correctly:

```
<a href="/ThePage/25" data-transition="slidedown">Click Here 1</a><!--This is working-->
```

But, these links *which have anchors* are not working:

```
<a href="/ThePage/25#3" data-transition="slidedown">Click Here 2</a><!--This is not working-->
<a href="/ThePage/25/#3" data-transition="slidedown">Click Here 3</a><!--This is not working-->
```

How to make those links that have `#` work with ajax navigation?

**Edit:** The page, which contains these links, contains some links to different articles. And `/ThePage/25` contains the full text of that articles. I want each link to go to somewhere inside `/ThePage/25`. So I've used `#`. (`#3` means the third article in the page)... Do you know any better way?

**Edit 2:** I'm simply trying to load/show a page and then jump within it...

**Edit 3:** My jump inside that page isn't a simple jumping. It's a custom handled jumping with `hashchange` event. But if there is any other method, I can change that page...

Comment: Why dont you do it from javascript? I feel thats a better and cleaner approach.. I had issues with `#` tags.

Comment: @SJGJ I have no idea about how I can do it from javascript. Can you make an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this from JS like this , I had problems with `#` tags  :

```
<a class='homeSet'>Home</a>
```

....

```
 $('body').on('click', '.homeSet', function(ev) {
    $.mobile.changePage('/home.html#myhome', {
        transition : "slide"
    });
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: This ignores the hash. (It is simply going to `/home.html`...)

Comment: do u have a `<div data-role="page" id="myhome">` in your `home.html` ?

Comment: No, As I said in the question, I don't want default jumping inside html. I have created a `hashchange` event in `home.html` and I do some things inside it...

Answer (score 6):

add rel="external" to any links that have an anchor # and you don't want to load via ajax.

New Links would be:

```
<a href="/ThePage/25#3" rel="external" data-transition="slidedown">Click Here 2</a><!--This is not working-->
<a href="/ThePage/25/#3" rel="external" data-transition="slidedown">Click Here 3</a>
```

See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html for more detail.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant use ajax navigation for the rest of the site

Comment: What's the purpose of the anchor if you're loading via ajax? You're trying to load a page and then jump within it?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Anyone figure this out yet?